# consolidate appropiate data from the whole value using condition

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, hashtable

I am getting value through the variable and querying the oracle DB through powershell

```
$query = "select col1,col2 from sometable where somevalue in ($value)
```

$value is getting input from hashtable

```
while($reader.read())
{
$reader.getvalue(0)+""+$reader.getvalue(1)
}
```

Now I should segregate the col1  value based on the condition that implies in col2

```
i.e)col2="ship" then the values of col1 should be in a variable named $value2
```

example:

123 car

234 bike

345 ship

908 ship

```
update col1 from table where col1 in ($value2)
```

$value 2 should have only 345 and 908.

Answer (score 0):

Determine output the `col2` value if `col1` is "ship", and collect it in a variable in the loop:

```
$value2 = while($reader.read())
{
    if($reader.getvalue(0) -eq "ship"){
        $reader.getvalue(1)
    }
}
```

Then join the values by comma for the `IN` clause:

```
$secondQuery = "update col1 from table where col1 in ($($value2 -join ','))"
```